# Inner Shadow in SVG path - Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg

The design in Figma is using an inner shadow effect in the SVG icon, I just started learning flutter so I am not sure if its fairly simple or if it isn't even possible. I saw some people using gradients or box shadow, but that's not it. Box shadow only creates a square shadow containing the SVG icon, not following the vector itself.

[image]

Comment: Inner shadows like this are possible with SVG.  When you export the Figma design as SVG, does it not work?

Comment: that's another weird thing, i exported as SVG and imported to flutter. it previews right with the shadows but when compiled to the phone it shows just the plain blue color. when i open the svg file on google chrome it also shows the inner shadow just right.

Comment: Are you using flutter_svg?  If so, it says on [their homepage](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg) that they don't support SVG filters yet.  Blurred shadows require filter support. You can check if your SVG uses SVG filter elements by looking for `<filter>` elements in the XML.